# Enthält der Duden und vergleichbare Werke alle gebräuchlichen, einfachen Komposita?

Tags: compound

Das der aktuellen deutschen Rechtschreibung zugrunde liegende Dokument das Wörterverzeichnis2006 [siehe IDS](http://www.ids-mannheim.de/service/reform/) enthält definitiv nicht alle Komposita, sondern legt durch Regeln fest, wie zusammengesetzte Wörter zu schreiben sind, falls sie heute oder in naher Zukunft verwendet werden.

Die darauf beruhenden Wörterbücher der deutschen Sprache listen viele der gängigen Kombinationen explizit auf.

Mir ist dabei unklar, ob hier ein gewisser Anspruch auf Vollständigkeit, z.B. mindestens alle Komposita aus bis zu zwei Komponenten aufzuführen, besteht, sofern sie lange genug gebräuchlich sind.

Nochmal anders formuliert. Wollen diese Wörterbücher helfen zu ermitteln, ob eine Wortkombination gebräuchlich ist?

Mir ist zum Beispiel aufgefallen, dass das Wort [Zuchtwart](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zuchtwart) nicht in [Duden online](http://www.duden.de/suchen/dudenonline/Zuchtwart) aufgeführt wird. Für jemanden ohne Bezug zur Hunde- und Katzenzucht klingt das Wort zu Recht nationalsozialistisch vorbelastet. Innerhalb der Hunde- und Katzenzuchtvereine beschreibt es eine etablierte Funktion, die eben so bezeichnet wird.

Das Wort ist also weder neu noch unbekannt und die Kombination ist ziemlich einfach.

Folgt die Auswahl der Worte hier Regeln oder wird willkürlich (z.B. durch Abstimmung in der Redaktion) ausgewählt?

Comment: Was genau ist jetzt die Frage? .. Auf jeden Fall, vollständig wird es nie etwas geben, auch nicht, wenn man es auf Wortkombinationen aus zwei Wörtern reduziert.

Comment: Ich rede nicht von möglichen, sondern von gebräuchlichen Kombinationen und die sind endlich.

Comment: Ich denke, man muss 2-3 verschiedene Quellen zusammenziehen und erhält dadurch eine nahe zu vollständige Liste. Aber selbst dann fehlen noch Wörter, vor allen Dingen Wörter aus der Internet- und/oder Jugendsprache (und ich rede hier von hochdeutschen Wörtern, nicht solche die auf Dialekt basieren). Wörter finden - imho - nicht sehr schnell ihren Weg in den Duden. Ins Wiki finden Wörter dabei sehr schnell ihren Weg, weswegen Wiki überladen ist, und nicht als Quelle dienen kann (zumindest nicht für deine Fragestellung). Wie es mit anderen Quellen aussieht, I'm sure, I've no idea.

Comment: Ich meine, dass irgendein Wörterbuch (war aber glaub ich englische Sprache oder Übersetzung engl-de) eine Umfrage gemacht hat, welches Wort aufgenommen werden soll. Das bezieht sich zwar nicht direkt auf deine Frage, aber ich denke, theoretisch könnte auch der Duden sowas machen. Vllt gab es da auch mal was.

Comment: Meine Beobachtung ist auch, dass zusammengesetzte Fachwörter oft nicht im Duden stehen. Wie geläufig, und wem sie geläufig sind - das dürfte i.d.R. unbekannt sein. Dass Vollständigkeit unmöglich ist - dem muss ich aber widersprechen. Aus einer endlichen Liste aller einfachen Substantive läßt sich auch nur eine endliche Liste an Kombinationen aus 2 Wörtern bilden.

Answer (score 2):

Kurze Antwort:

Der Duden nimmt neue Wörter auf, die allgemein verwendet werden. "[Cool](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/cool)" stand besimmt nicht in den ersten Dudenausgaben, aber über die Jugendsprache (und die Hartnäckigkeit mit der sich das Wort gehalten hat) kam es in den Duden.

Ebenso werden Worte, die nicht mehr verwendet werden im allgemeinen Sprachgebrauch, wieder entfernt. Möglich, dass "Zuchtwart" schon mal im Duden stand.

Was ist jetzt nun "allgemein"? Siehe hierzu die lange Antwort.

Lange Antwort:

[Wie kommt ein Wort in den Duden?](http://www.duden.de/ueber_duden/wie-kommt-ein-wort-in-den-duden)